# Is it legal (in Europe, Belgium) to publish prices from unaffiliated establishments?

Tags: business, finance, competition

Say I want to publish the pricelist from the store down the road, without their consent, on my own website. Is this legal? If not, what should I do to enable the publishing of other businesses prices?